# Verify if an entered email address exists or not

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I successfully done e-mail validation using a regular expression but I want to verify if an email address exists or not which is entered by the user.

Comment: So what you are trying to achieve without the email address? In order to verify if the email address exist, only way would be to send an message to it with some form of verification code/ logic within it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can check an e-mail address without sending an e-mail for the user to confirm with some kind of link or code (just like a confirmation e-mail you get on your inbox when you register in some website).

If you are trying to check if what the user has typed is an e-mail, you can try and use [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
var email = "jonhdoe@example.com";
var pattern = "/(.*@.*\.\w{2,})/";
var isEmail = pattern.test(email);
```

**EDIT**

Following the edit that has been done to your question, the only way you can validate if the email actually exists is by sending an email with a link that redirects to your website (something like http://example.com/validateEmail?secret=specificUserSecret) or a code that can be entred on a validation form on your website.

In the example link, the value of secret is a random string that would link the user (that I'll assume that is signing up on your website) to the email you're trying to validate.

The example with a code, the code could be a randomly generated string that would be sent to the email that the user has specified (again, assuming that the user is signing up on your website). Then, the user would have to copy and paste that same code into a form on your website.